# aggregate/compress data with comma separated values against a key using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have data which looks like this:

```
user    document     score
 A         ABC        .98
 A         BCD        .91
 A         CDE        .90
 B         ABC        .68
 B         XYZ        .60
```

and so on.
I want to compress/aggregate it to:

```
 user         document                 score
  A       'ABC','BCD','CDE'     '.98','0.91','0.90'
  B       'ABC','XYZ'           '.68','.60'
```

and so on.

I know how to do it column by column by using this formula:

```
(df['document'].str.split(', ')
                .groupby(df['user'])
                .agg(lambda x: ', '.join(set(y for z in x for y in z)))
                .reset_index())
```

but if I try to do it for both columns, it shows me an error. How do I do it? Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**:
To wrap them in addition quotes

```
df.astype(str).groupby('user').agg(lambda x: "'{0}'".format("','".join(x)))

Out[1363]:
               document                score
user
A     'ABC','BCD','CDE'  '0.98','0.91','0.9'
B           'ABC','XYZ'         '0.68','0.6'
```

**Original**

Try this:

```
df.astype(str).groupby('user').agg(','.join)
```

Comment: This will only grab the first series.  You would need to cast the `score` series to `str` before it would pick the second as well.

Comment: `df.astype(str)`

Comment: @QuangHoang: Thanks.

Comment: @user3483203: yes, I didn't notice `score` is `float`. The fix is simple using `astype` before `groupby` as edited.

Comment: its working, but its not coming in "QUOTES". Any solution for that ?

Comment: Great! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace()` with regex and `str.cat()` methods:

```
df.groupby('user').agg(lambda x: x.astype(str).replace(r'(.*)', r"'\1'", regex=True).str.cat(sep = ', '))
```

Result:

```
                 document                  score
user                                            
A     'ABC', 'BCD', 'CDE'  '0.98', '0.91', '0.9'
B            'ABC', 'XYZ'          '0.68', '0.6'
```